# Green rectangle for mouse dialogs after video driver update?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

After installing the updates for my nvidia card and CUDA on ubuntu, this green border appears for every window created by pointing the mouse somewhere:

[image]

Why this happens? And how can I solve it?